# Zerobrane Output Window truncates output displayed

Tags: debugging, configuration, output, coronasdk, zerobrane

I have been unsuccessful in discovering how to force the "output window" in Zerobrane to show the entire output.  My setup is inserting a CR at about column 80 followed by a few characters and ... on the next line.  My dozen searches for various key words has not produced a solution.  Any solutions to this issue?  I'd think some configuration option might set this up but ????.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any truncation in v1.30 or v1.40 of ZeroBrane Studio (I've tried with lines of up to 10,000 characters in length). You may want to upgrade if you are using some of the older versions.

Comment: well, I am not imagining it.  the lines are chopped off and an ellipsis is tacked on.

Comment: v1.30 I have not found any way to upgrade to v 1.4 & have looked many times for it.  To develper: I have struggled w/ this product. it has not lived up to my expectations. this problem was reported weeks ago with no response.  how do you have an output window that does not show all?  exactly how do you debug with that?  If this problem whatever the cause is can not be fixed I'll have to go elsewhere.  and you can refund my money.

Comment: v1.40 is available on the project website: https://studio.zerobrane.com/. Output from the following code `print("Long"..('-'):rep(100000).."output")` is displayed without abbreviations. Does this work for you? Do you have a short example to reproduce?